# Pytest - Test directory specific conftest.py to override pytest_terminal_summary

Tags: pytest

Searching over the net and pytest documentation, I am bit confused.
**Is it or is it not recommended to have test directory specific hooks in their own respective `conftest.py`** ??

While the [doc](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/writing_plugins.html#pluginorder) says

> Note that pytest does not find conftest.py files in deeper nested sub directories at tool startup. It is usually a good idea to keep your conftest.py file in the top level test or project root directory.

The very next paragraph describes having per-directory `conftest.py`

**The issue I am having is** that the existing `pytest` framework we have has few `globals` defined in the root `conftest.py` And then some scripts have `import contest`

I wish to override the `pytest_terminal_summary` for few of my testcases where I need to parse a file and display results

But the presence of local `contest.py` in the test directory, raises error about the `globals`

```
contest.py    # Root conftest.py
global logfile

tests/mytests/
              conftest.py
              my_own_test.py

# pytest my_own_test.py
E    module 'conftest' has no attribute 'logfile'
```

Any workarounds for this ? I am not sure if I can get of the existing `import contest`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to workaround this by having my `pytest_terminal_summary` hook in py file. Then including that as `pytest_plugins=[...]` in the test module.

**Note:** I had to invoke the tests with `python3 -m pytest` to let it find the locally available module, but that is ok